# django app engine multiple domains, multiple settings files

Tags: django, google-app-engine, wsgi, django-wsgi

I'm new to Google App Engine and am trying to port my Django application to use that. I haven't been able to find too much on this and don't think multitenancy is what I'm looking for (seems to be for more or less identical apps with different data sources?), but my scenario is this:

I have multiple domains and currently have different settings file (with seperate WSGI files) which works great for my current Apache configuration, but I'm trying to migrate over to GAE and can't seem to figure out how to do something similiar based on domain name? Really, all I critically need is a seperate urls file based on the domain name (datastore is the same on both), although it would be ideal to have a separate settings file so I don't have to load unused apps, preprocessors, etc on sites that don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly have two different versions of the app, they both will use the same data store, since source code of both versions can be different, you can specify different configurations/settings for each of them.

coming to accessing different versions, you can either route through your dashboard/domain settings and/or fine tune it with help of [traffic splitting](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting#The_Types_of_Splitting)

hope it helps